# how to allow communication with an application from outside the network?

Tags: spring, email, networking

I have an application running in my personal network. This application can send emails to users and they can acknowledge the receipt via the email they receive as long as they are on my personal network. This is because they have to access the application to perform the acknowledge action.

I want to extend this and see if I can allow acknowledgements via emails from outside the network as well. I know I have to change my application to do this but not sure which way to go. Can some one throw some light?

My application is a spring based web application.

Comment: whoever downvoted - please mention why as well. Helps understand what is wrong in asking for an approach

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to configure your firewall to allow outside access to whatever port the app runs on.
2. You need to configure port fowarding on your gateway to direct outside traffic to the system running your app (unless your gateway is the server running the app).

After that you should just be able to go to youroutfacingip:portforapp

```
for example http://123.456.78.90:12345
```

in a web browser anywhere

you can setup DNS if you want to use a URL instead of an ip.

Keep in mind, anyone can go to this url, so make sure it has access control.

Comment: would this still be the same if I have a web service that the email can reach out to? Sorry if the question is dumb, but I am new to this.